# How to explain this behavior of sprintf?

Tags: c, string, printf

So the case was simple: I needed to add a character in front of a c string.

So I had my code:

```
char *a = "2233b";
char output[100];   
char toAdd = '-';

strcpy(output, a);
printf("\noutput=%s", output);
sprintf(output, "%c%s",  toAdd, a);
printf("\noutput=%s", output);
```

And the output was as expected:

> `output=2233b`
>   `output=-2233b`

Ok, so far so good. Now the case changed and I wanted to add more characters before a c string, so I configured the code like so:

```
char *a = "2233b";
char output[100];   
char toAdd = '-';

strcpy(output, a);
printf("\noutput=%s", output);
sprintf(output, "%c%s",  toAdd, a);
printf("\noutput=%s", output);
sprintf(output, "%c%s",  toAdd, output);
printf("\noutput=%s", output);
```

I expected the output to be:

> `output=2233b`
>   `output=-2233b`
>   `output=--2233b`

But this was not the case and the following output was printed on my screen:

> `output=2233b`
>   `output=-2233b`
>   `output=-------`

[Check working example here](http://codepad.org/DC7dKCmT)

Why is does `output` contain this value?
Because the format is just the character (`%c`) `toAdd` (`'-'`) and a string (`%s`) which is `output` and contains (`"-2233b"`).

So why isn't the last output containing `"--2233b"`? And how come the characters of `output` are all converted to `'-'`?

Comment: Check out this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973572/can-the-input-and-output-strings-to-sprintf-be-the-same

Comment: Side note: to add a character in front of a c string: `memmove(&output[1], &output[0], strlen(output) + 1); output[0] = toAdd;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard prohibits passing buffers that overlap for input and output, so the behavior is undefined.

If you are interested in finding out why you get multiple dashes, here is what's going on: the problem is that when you pass `output` as an *input* to `sprintf`, the function behaves like a dog chasing its own tail: it writes the first character into `output` *before* reading its first character, and then its writing "front-runs" its reading as it tries, unsuccessfully, to process the `%s` format: new characters get added to the output right at the point where the function is reading.

To fix this problem, make a temporary copy of `output` before passing it to `sprintf`.

Comment: Well, that makes sense actually. Did you just assume this is the case (because what else could it be, huh?) or did you take a look at the source code?

Comment: @moffeltje I did not look up the source code, I just tried to think through implementing `sprintf` myself, and how my implementation would behave in a situation like this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is in

```
 sprintf(output, "%c%s",  toAdd, output);
```

Here, you're reading from and writing to `output`, in a single sequenced statement. This  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To quote `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.6, the `sprintf()` function

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Uh, sorry realized to late that you already posted an answer.

Comment: Yep, I falsely assumed this wouldn't be a problem. Another prove to myself that the full documentation of a apparently simple function is more beneficial than I might think. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @brauner no issues, :-)

Comment: @moffeltje Well, as we can see, we should not assume. You're welcome, BTW. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh assumptions are deadly, isn't it?

Comment: @moffeltje I should say , yes, at least, __most__ of the times. Better, read the docs and be sure, say goodbye to "assumptions." :-)

Comment: @moffeltje: `sprintf` is hardly a simple function :P

Answer (score 1):

This is invoking undefined behavior as is mentioned on the corresponding `man` page on *nix systems and in the `C` and also in the `POSIX` standard.

```
NOTES
   Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following

       sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);

   to append text to buf.  However, the standards explicitly  note  that  the
   results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when call‐
   ing sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf().  Depending on  the
   version  of  gcc(1) used, and the compiler options employed, calls such as
   the above will not produce the expected results.

   The glibc implementation of the functions snprintf() and vsnprintf()  con‐
   forms  to  the  C99  standard,  that is, behaves as described above, since
   glibc version 2.1.  Until glibc 2.0.6, they would return -1 when the  out‐
   put was truncated.
```