# Adding integers as char to create a string in C

Tags: c, string, turbo-c

I wanted to ask if there is a way to add integers as char values and create a string. I have written some code but only last digit is detected

```
void binary(int decimal) {
  int modulus;
  char bin[9];
  while (decimal != 0) {
    modulus = decimal % 2;
    sprintf(bin, "%d", modulus);
    if (modulus == 1) {
      decimal--;
    }
    decimal = decimal / 2;
  }
  puts(bin);
}
```

If the decimal is `10` then the holds only `1` instead `0101`. How can I fix it? I am using Turbo C++ 3.0.

Comment: `sprintf(bin, "%d", modulus);` You always write  from front.

Comment: It's not trivial because it writes the digits reversed. I had posted an answer but it prints the binary string reversed, so no good. recursion or reverse the string afterwards should solve it.

Comment: And to not always write from the front, increment your pointer (`bin`) every time you write to it (but maintain a reference to the start of the string for the return).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The expected result of OP is reversed. E.g `0101` : `10` (base 10)

Comment: I know that the answer would be reversed that is why I am taking result as a string and then reversing it to print as output.

Comment: NB: You don't need to decrement an odd value before dividing. E.g. 5/2 in integer division is 2, as it rounds down

Comment: BLUEPIXY's comment contains the answer. `sprintf` overrides the string, so you start anew in each iteration. You need to find a way to concatenate the strings

Comment: @king_nak _overrides_ -> _overwrites_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly your function with slight modifications and comments.

The binary string is still reversed though.

```
void binary(int decimal) {
  int modulus;
  char bin[9];
  char temp[2];   // temporary string for sprintf

  bin[0] = 0;     // initially binary string set to "" (empty string)

  while (decimal != 0) {
    modulus = decimal % 2;

    sprintf(temp, "%d", modulus);  // print '1' or '0' to temporary string
    strcat(bin, temp);             // concatenate temporary string to bin

    if (modulus == 1) {
      decimal--;
    }
    decimal = decimal / 2;
  }
  puts(bin);
}
```

There are more efficient ways to achieve this, especially makeing use of the  left shift operator (`<<`), that way you can construct the binary string directly without needing to reverse it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually made the same code from following the advice from the comments. However your code confirmed my code. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't that generate the number reversed?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it does, read the second sentence of the answer.

Comment: ok, so I'm undeleting my answer, it's simpler because it's not using temporary & strcat.

Comment: You could remove the `temp` and `strcat`by using `sprintf(bin, "%s%d", bin, modulus)`. Then, to get the string in the correct order, just reverse the parameters: `sprintf(bin, "%d%s", modulus, bin)`

Comment: @king_nak using `sprintf` to print a string into itself results definitely in undefined behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973572/can-the-input-and-output-strings-to-sprintf-be-the-same/

Answer (score 0):

of course, you're printing on the same `bin` location, not moving your "cursor".

Declare a pointer on the string and increment it after each `sprintf`, should work, since `sprintf` issues only 1 digit + null-termination char.

```
char bin[9];
char *ptr = bin;
  while (decimal != 0) {
    modulus = decimal % 2;
    sprintf(ptr, "%d", modulus);
    ptr++;
```

that generates the string, but reversed (because lower bits are processed first). Just print it reversed or reverse it afterwards.

```
 int l = strlen(bin);
 for (i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
     putc(bin[l-i-1]);
 }
 putc("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that prints a decimal as binary:

```
void print_binary(int num)
{
    int pos = (sizeof(int) * 8) - 1;
    printf("%10d: ", num);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(int) * 8); i++) {
        char c = num & (1 << pos) ? '1' : '0';
        putchar(c);
        if (!((i + 1) % 8))
            putchar(' ');
        pos--;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

output:

```
        42: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101010
```

Comment: Isn't there anyway to create a string using integers? Your answer is what I wanted, ir is just that I wanted to learn what I have done wrong