# c snprintf used to concat string

Tags: c, linux, string

I'm using the following function on two different computers.  One one computer is running Ubuntu and the other OS X.  The function works on OS X, but not Ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXBUF 256

char *safe_strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) {
    snprintf(dest, n, "%s%s", dest, src);
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    char st1[MAXBUF+1] = "abc";
    char st2[MAXBUF+1] = "def";
    char* st3;
    printf("%s + %s = ",st1, st2);
    
    st3 = safe_strncat(st1, st2, MAXBUF);
            
    printf("%s\n",st3);
    printf("original string = %s\n",st1);
}
```

Compile and run on Ubuntu

> gcc concat_test.c -o concat_test
>
> ./concat_test
>
> abc + def = def
>
> original string = def

Compile and run in Xcode in OS X

> abc + def = abcdef
>
> original string = abcdef

1. Why does this work on mac and not on Ubuntu?
2. Should it work on Ubuntu?
3. Should it work on Mac?
4. I could swear it used to work in Ubuntu until recently, but I don't know what would have changed to make it stop working?
5. Could compiler settings have anything to do with this working or not?

Comment: is strncat a good alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior because you pass the destination buffer as one of the source strings of your `snprintf()` format. This is not supported:

> **7.21.6.5 The `snprintf` function**
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
>              const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. **If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

(emphasis mine).

The implementation of `snprintf` differs between Ubuntu (glibc) and OS/X (Apple libc, based on BSD sources). The behavior differs and cannot be relied upon as it is undefined in all cases.

You can implement `safe_strcat()` this way:

```
#include <string.h>

char *safe_strcat(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    char *p = memchr(dest, '\0', size);
    if (p != NULL) {
        strncat(p, src, size - (p - dest) - 1);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Notes:

- do not call this function `safe_strncat()`, it is really a safe version of `strcat()`.
- pass the size of the destination array after the destination pointer itself, not after the source pointer.
- returning the destination pointer does not allow the caller to detect truncation. You could instead return the length of the result if the destination array had been large enough, like `snprintf()`, you it would still not tell the caller if the destination was not null terminated before the call (for `safe_strcat` and `safe_strncat`).

You can use the same model for safe versions of `strcpy`, `strncat` and `strncpy` (but not implementing `strncpy()`'s counter-intuitive semantics):

```
char *safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    if (size > 0) {
        *dest = '\0';
        strncat(dest, src, size - 1);
    }
    return dest;
}

char *safe_strncat(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src, size_t n) {
    char *p = memchr(dest, '\0', size);
    if (p != NULL) {
        if (n > size - (p - dest) - 1)
            n = size - (p - dest) - 1;
        strncat(p, src, n);
    }
    return dest;
}

char *safe_strncpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src, size_t n) {
    if (size > 0) {
        if (n > size - 1)
            n = size - 1;
        *dest = '\0';
        strncat(dest, src, n);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> snprintf(dest, n, "%s%s", dest, src);

This line caused undefined behaviour because you are overwriting the buffer `dest`. Because it's not defined, it's pointless to work out why it works on one machine and not the other.

More details can be found here: [Is sprintf(buffer, "%s […]", buffer, […]) safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283354/is-sprintfbuffer-s-buffer-safe)